# Does `ElementMeshInterpolation` work for arbitrary orders?

Tags: interpolation, finite-element-method

Mathematica will not, in general, do arbitrary order interpolation on unstructured grids:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
f[x_, y_] := (1 - x^2 + y^2);
mesh = ToElementMesh[Disk[]];
coords = mesh["Coordinates"];
vals = f @@ # & /@ coords;
if = Interpolation[MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {coords, vals}], InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

results in a message saying `Interpolation::udeg: Interpolation on unstructured grids is currently only supported for InterpolationOrder->1 or InterpolationOrder->All. Order will be reduced to 1.`

On the other hand if I use `ElementMeshInterpolation`:

```
emif2 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, vals, InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

It seems to have no problem. It also seems to only actually give the first order interpolation no matter what I specify. If I plot the difference between `Interpolation` and `ElementMeshInterpolation` run at first and second order I get identical plots.

```
if1 = Interpolation[MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {coords, vals}], InterpolationOrder -> 1]    
emif1 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, vals, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
emif2 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, vals, InterpolationOrder -> 2]
GraphicsGrid[{{ContourPlot[emif1[x, y] - if1[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]], 
   ContourPlot[emif2[x, y] - if1[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]]}}]
```

[image]

Is `ElementMeshInterpolation` silently falling back to 1st order? Is there any way to get higher order interpolations on an unstructured grid?

Comment: if you generally mean "arbitrary," then, no, the interpolation order can only be `1` or `2`, and it depends on the order of the underlying mesh.  OTOH, your example seems to raise a more particular question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ElementMeshInterpolation` seems to default to the order of the underlying `mesh`, which is 2 in the example.  Alter the order of `mesh` to get an order 1 mesh & interpolation, and you can construct two different interpolations.

```
mesh1 = MeshOrderAlteration[mesh, 1];
vals1 = f @@@ mesh1["Coordinates"];

if1 = Interpolation[MapThread[{##} &, {coords, vals}], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
emif1 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh1}, vals1, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
emif2 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, vals, InterpolationOrder -> 2];
GraphicsGrid[{{ContourPlot[
    emif1[x, y] - if1[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]], 
   ContourPlot[emif2[x, y] - if1[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You may want to compare `emif1` and `emif2` with `if1 = Interpolation[MapThread[{##} &, {mesh1["Coordinates"], vals1}], InterpolationOrder -> 1]`.  For some reason, I didn't grok the purpose of the plots at first.